# Convert Spark Json Tuple List to String fields

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

How to convert arraylist of string to string fields in spark (json_tuple)

```java
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
strList.add("name");
strList.add("age");
```

I have a JSON column

```json
"json_blob": {
    "name": "test1",
    "age": 30.0
    "order_id": 2.0
  }
}
```

ExpectedOutput

```json
"name" : "test1",
"age" : 30,
"json_blob": {
    "order_id": 2.0
  }
```

Here I want to extract all the columns which are in the str list as a separate column
I tried by passing directly the string its working

```java
resultDataSet.select(col("jsob_blob"), json_tuple(col("jsob_blob"), "name", "age")).toDF().show();
```

But the incoming stringlist will be dynamic . How do i convert the string list to spark multiple string fields

I tried this way also
but the columns returning null values.

```java
resultDataSetJoined.select(col("jsob_blob")), json_tuple(col("jsob_blob")), strList)).toDF().show();
```